# Where can I host GeoServer that will allow multiple users to edit on ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, geoserver, cloud-gis, enterprise

We have several spatial data editors spread across the US, each having to access the same data. What we need is a multi-user spatial database that can be served up through GeoServer, hosted on the cloud, and accessed/edited within ArcMap. Does this exist?

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with hosting GeoServer in the cloud. My employers provide this as a service to several clients, but you could manage it yourself with little effort. Googling for "geoserver commercial cloud" turns up a number of companies offering this service.

[ArcMap/ArcGis should have no difficulty in using WFS-T](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/data-editing-with-wfs-services.htm) to edit your data layers via GeoServer and a PostGIS (or other spatial) database either on the same host or an RDS platform (if you go with AWS).

Answer (score 1):

Cloud hosting of Geoserver is available probably on most cloud service providers.
Be mindful of caching configuration, or tile caches, this is potentially where you may get unstuck if you have dynamic space setup in AWS for example. But if you have managed Geoserver caching before in a fixed space environment, thats the way I would go.

Also be mindful of Highly available or clustered Geoserver installations and transaction queues, as sometimes the queues can be out of sync. (might be easier to manage transaction queues on one instance only, caching services on another instance, or similar, a good article can be found here. https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/clustering/clustering/passive/passive.html. )

Geoserver supports OGC WFS-T  see here for more detail.
https://www.ogc.org/standards/wfs and https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html

ArcMap supports WFS-T as per previous answers.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out! Seems like the best way forward is to find a cloud service that will deploy GeoServer and start building our database. Then connect to it using WFS-t. And this allows for multiple people to edit the same data? Does it support versioning?

Comment: Not sure about versioning support. It depends on underlying db technology as well, and also what level of maturity you want with your versioning, im not 100% sure though. There might be another tread about this somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

For use with GeoServer, my experience is that it works more easily with QGIS.

If you are bound by using ArcMap, I may suggest using ArcGIS Online to host your spatial data (perhaps from GeoServer) and then connect to it using ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro.

You can get a free developer account (https://developers.arcgis.com/sign-up/) giving access and quite a reasonable amount of online storage. In addition, this also gives the possibility to edit the layers online directly (using Mac/Windows).

Comment: Thanks for contributing to my question PGerrits. My understanding is that ArcGIS online is its own server though, so wouldn’t that negate any need for GeoServer?